# Smarty PHP Multi-Select for custom fields

Tags: php, smarty, multi-select

I purchased a script built by someone who used smarty, it's a social network platform.

I have an issue with making the dropdown select field mulitiselect , and I didn't find a solution.

In the admin area, there's an option to add custom fields in the registration form, there are only three options : Textbox, text area, selectbox (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itw8n.jpg

Once an option of that custom field is selected during the registration process, it will be seen in the profile page.

I can't seem to figure out how to make that field a multiselect one.

here's the code of the custom-field .tpl file

```
{elseif $custom_field['type'] == "selectbox"} 
               <select name="fld_{$custom_field['field_id']}" multiple="multiple" size="5"> 
                   <option {if $custom_field['value'] == ""}selected{/if} value="none">{__("Select")} {__($custom_field['label'])} </option> 
                   {foreach $custom_field['options'] as $id => $value} 
                       <option {if $custom_field['value'] == $value}selected{/if} value="{$id}">{$value}</option> 
                   {/foreach}
```

I added : multiple="multiple", the field change and i can select multiple options by holding ctrl , but i don't know if it's working or not knowing that i only see one selected option in the profile page.

here's the code in profile.php :

/* get custom fields */
$smarty->assign('custom_fields', $user->get_custom_fields( array("for" => "user", "get" => "profile", "node_id" => $profile['user_id']) ));

here's the code to show the selected options in profile.tpl :

```
{foreach $custom_fields['other'] as $custom_field}{if $custom_field['value']} {$custom_field['label']}{$custom_field['value']} </li> {/if} {/foreach}
```

Do you please have an idea how to be able to select more than one option and display the selected ones correctly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you cleared Smarty's cache after you made template changes?

Comment: @ Seva Kalashnikov Thank you for your reply, no, i didn't clear the cache, should I?

Comment: Yes, google for how it should be done, lmk if it worked or not

Comment: @ Seva Kalashnikov Ok thank you, I will clear the cache and will keep you posted.

Comment: @ Seva Kalashnikov Hi again, I cleared the cache but still have the same issue. Maybe something is missing in the codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that after modifying your select to multiple you still consider a result of its work as a single value but not as an array. First, you need to change the name of select to `name="fld_{$custom_field['field_id']}[]"` which is mean that select can have a few values and it will send it to backend as an array of values. Second, you need to manage this array in your backend and save all its values. Third, you need to treat with it as with array in your front and `{if $custom_field['value'] == $value}`
will not be a single value so you need to check if the `$value` is in the array `$custom_field['value']` like `{if $value|in_array($custom_field['value'])}`. And I think everything will work as you expect